# using an asp.net literal inside the <title> element

Tags: c#, asp.net

This is such a simple scenario that I can't see what can possibly be going wrong. I'm using asp.net 4.0 (haven't tried older versions)

```
<title>Welcome to Page: <asp:Literal ID="Literal1" runat="server">
                                                </asp:Literal></title>
```

When the page is rendered, the title comes out as just the contents of the literal control without the "welcome to page" text in it. If you don't believe me, try it for yourself

Can anyone explain?

Andy

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is not allowed in ASP.NET any of the version. No literals can be added in headsection.

But if you want to change the title Dynamically then from Code behind you can directly change the Page Title. here is the Example.

```
Page.Title = "Welcome to Page: Home Page";
```

Comment: Thanks, I had no idea of that. It would be nice if it actually told you that rather than behaving in such an arbitrary manner. I found that removing the runat=server on the head element worked just as well - I suspect these two things are related.

Comment: @Bhavik. Is there any documentation about this : "This is not allowed in ASP.NET any of the version. No literals can be added in headsection." ?

Comment: I am not sure about the document, but you need to add this in the code behind, in any of the event or section. I am using this since I was using ASP.NET 2.0

Answer (score 1):

Set it on PageLoad() using:

```
Page.Title = "My Page Title";
```

If you're doing this to set the same title on lot's of pages, do this on the MasterPage, or inherit a BasePage that does this on PageLoad().